# Space-saving itemize in table

Tags: tables, itemize

I want to use a bullet list in a table. My problem with this is that there is a lot of space to the left and basically half my table is empty.

So I searched for a solution on StackExchange and found one. It introduced the command `\tabitem` for which `\begin{itemize}` isn't needed and which doesn't take up as much space to the left (though it still could be less).

`\tabitem` is defined via:

```
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
```

However, it has its own problem: The space to the left isn't the same everywhere. Take a look at this table:
[image]

Furthermore, I want a second level of indentation. So I tried using the normal `\begin{itemize}` and `\item` because it comes with a lot of space to the left anyways.

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\setlength\hsize{0.33\hsize}\setlength\linewidth{\hsize}}X|>{\setlength\hsize{0.33\hsize}\setlength\linewidth{\hsize}}X|>{\setlength\hsize{0.33\hsize}\setlength\linewidth{\hsize}}X|}
        \hline
        I-Dateneinheiten & S-Dateneinheiten & U-Dateneinheiten \\
        \hline
        \tabitem Datenübertragung
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Bei gesetztem Poll-Bit: Empfänger muss mit Quittung reagieren.
                \item Sequenznummer N(R) quittiert korrekten Empfang aller Dateneinheiten bis N(R)-1.
            \end{itemize}
        &       
        \tabitem Steuerung des Datenflusses
        \begin{itemize}
            \item z.B. Sendeaufruf, Bestätigung empfangener Daten, ...
            \item Kodierung der Befehle bzw. Meldungen durch S-Bits (Supervisory Funktionsbits)
        \end{itemize}
        &

        \tabitem Steuerung der Verbindung
        \begin{itemize}
            \item keine Empfangsfolgenummern
            \item Kodierung durch M-Bits (Modifier Funktionsbits)
        \end{itemize}
        \\
        \hline

    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

However, as you can see, it doesn't stand out in the center or right column because `\tabitem` doesn't put its text far enough to the left.

How can this be fixed?

Summary of what I want:

- Items without wasting space to the left.
- At least 2 levels of indentation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `enumitem` package and the `nosep` option to `\begin{itemize}` might help.

Comment: @egreg Doesn't work. ([code](http://pastebin.com/ujphBJSp), [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/VcYFcaQ.png)) Or I used it wrong. (I of course put `\usepackage{enumitem}` to the beginning of the file.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution based on `enumitem`: it consists in using the `itemize` environment with options `wide=0pt,leftmargin=*`, and defining a `tabitemize` environment, which neutralises vertical skips, to be used if the contents of the cell has to begin  with an `itemize` environment. Also, I simplified your use of the `X` columns:

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{booktabs, array, enumitem, ragged2e, tabularx, makecell}
\setcellgapes{4pt}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \newcommand{\tablistcommand}{%
      \leavevmode\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
    }

    \newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
    \setlist[tabitemize]{%
      leftmargin = * ,
      label = \textbullet ,
      nosep ,
      before = \tablistcommand ,
      after = \tablistcommand
    }

    \begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{table}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{3}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|}}
        \hline
        I-Dateneinheiten & S-Dateneinheiten & U-Dateneinheiten \\
        \hline
        \begin{tabitemize}%
        \item Datenübertragung
            \begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=0pt]
                \item Bei gesetztem Poll-Bit: Empfänger muss mit Quittung reagieren.
                \item Sequenznummer N(R) quittiert korrekten Empfang aller Dateneinheiten bis N(R)-1.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{tabitemize}
        &
       \begin{tabitemize}%
        \item Steuerung des Datenflusses
        \begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=0pt]
            \item z.B. Sendeaufruf, Bestätigung empfangener Daten, ...
            \item Kodierung der Befehle bzw. Meldungen durch S-Bits (Supervisory Funktionsbits)
        \end{itemize}
        \end{tabitemize}
        &
       \begin{tabitemize}%
        \item Steuerung der Verbindung
        \begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=0pt]
            \item keine Empfangsfolgenummern
            \item Kodierung durch M-Bits (Modifier Funktionsbits)
        \end{itemize}
        \end{tabitemize}
        \\[-4pt]
        \hline

    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is a bit messed up and I have too little understanding of it to get it right. Can you please fix it?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I should have checked every thing displayed fine. Fixed.

Comment: Still, why does for example the table end twice? I put [this part](http://pastebin.com/9dzRVuMC) at the start of my file and [this part](http://pastebin.com/87FTpghu) where the old table used to be. It certainly makes the indentation in the table look good. However, [it puts weird lines everywhere](http://i.imgur.com/Zg0953i.png). [Those lines also appear on all other pages.](http://i.imgur.com/W82l1vW.png) My document is a report, btw., not an article.

Comment: The table (and document) ending twice is just an error in copy-pasting. I've fixed that. The  weird lines, as you say, is just the `showframe` option of geometry. I often use it to check tables don't overflow in the margin, but you can safely remove the option. As to the `report` instead of `article` class, I've changed that, but note I couldn't guess: you didn't post a full code.

Comment: Thank you! :) Of course you couldn't know that the document type I'm using is `report`. I just thought that maybe using a document type other than `article` could cause problems. (Posting all of the code would've been a little much and there are graphics included ... copyrighted graphics, to make matters worse ...)